# Get jar file downloaded using Java

Tags: java, jar, download, nexus

I have to retrieve some jar files to local with Java code, but this is a specific case:

1. these jars are on Nexus, so without credentiels information I'd get 401 Error. I do have an account but how should I provide them together with the URLs ?
2. Which Object type shall I use to store the jars ?

Thanks a lot !

---

***Update***:

Thanks to @EJP's solution I added an `Authenticator`. But then I was stuck by `protocol exception: server redirected too many times`. I tried by adding `CookieManager` but did not work. The final solution that I used is:

```
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

    URL url = new URL(path);

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    InputStream in = null;
    byte[] encodedPassword = (login + ":" + pwd).getBytes();
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoder.encode(encodedPassword));

    conn.connect();
    in = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: what kind of credentials do you have?? any reference link ??

Comment: See `java.net.Authenticator`.